# Makefile first rule target

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to learn `make` using simply three files.

foo.h

```
#ifndef __foo_H_
#define __foo_H_

void print();

#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"


void print()
{
    printf("Hello World !");
}
```

main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

When I use the following makefile, everything runs fine

makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I.
DEPS = foo.h
OBJ = foo.o main.o 

.PHONY: clean

main: $(OBJ)
        gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
        rm *.o
```

The above works because `make` by default runs the first target(Which I read basically everywhere).

If I use the below makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I.
DEPS = foo.h
OBJ = foo.o main.o 

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm *.o

main: $(OBJ)
        gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Calling `make` on the above makefile runs only `make clean` because `make` by default runs the first rule.

The problem is with this makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I.
DEPS = foo.h
OBJ = foo.o main.o 

.PHONY: clean

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
        gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
        rm *.o
```

In the above makefile using `make` I get

```
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c -I.
gcc -c -o main.o main.c -I.
gcc -o main foo.o main.o -I.
```

Why doesn't `make` just build the `.o` files and stop since it is the first target, why does it go on to build main as well? There is no where that I've specified in the first rule to build main.

Comment: Presumably the rule is that the first *specific* target will be made.  An implicit pattern rule like `%.o: %.c $(DEPS)` does not specify a specific target.

Comment: @j_random_hacker But isn't the pattern a valid target.? So if I were to  use a makefile which only builds the object files using the above pattern, then `make` expects that nothing should happen, isn't that weird?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, if I only specify the pattern, then `make` says "make: *** No targets.  Stop."

Comment: An implicit pattern rule does not specify a target.  It can only match, and therefore apply to, a target that is already specified some other way -- either via an "ordinary" target rule, or a target specified on the `make` command line, or as a result of a dependency from one of these.  (Imagine if your only rule started with `%.o: %.c $(DEPS)` -- how would `make` know what to replace the `%` with?  Should it replace it with `yabbadabbadoo`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "first target" rule only counts *explicit* targets.  It doesn't count implicit targets, such as suffix rules or pattern rules.

Consider: how would make determine that it should build the `.o` files?  Which `.o` files should it build?  How would make understand that it should build the ones in the variable `OBJ`, versus any other variable?

Comment: But can't that pattern be used as a one liner to create object files for all `.c` files ?

Comment: That pattern rule will be applied to all requested/needed targets that match `%.o` but that rule itself doesn't specify any explicit targets that need building. Specifically make does not go looking for targets to build. It builds only what you have told it to build (and what it determines needs to be built to build that).

Comment: @Kartik Anand: No.  That pattern says "if you have a .c and you want to build a .o, you can do it with this recipe".  It's an abstract statement.  Make has no facility that allows it to understand what _all `.c` files_ means.  It will never (by itself) just look through all the files in the directory and choose ones which seem to match some pattern, and build it.  Make will only ever build targets you've explicitly asked it to build, either by an explicit target in the makefile or from the command line (e.g., `make foo.o`).

Comment: More specifically, that pattern can be used as _part of_ a solution to create object files for all `.c` files.  But you still need to say explicitly what objects you want to build.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a good section of the manual to point you at but haven't found anything specific and concrete to use. The answer to the question, as far as I know, is that a pattern rule is not a target and the default target must, as its name indicates, be a target.

Were you using a static pattern rule (which does define targets) then your expectation would almost be correct as make would pick the first such file and build just that in this case (not all as you might expect just the first).

Comment: Even I was thinking the same, but I couldn't find it anywhere written explicitly.

Comment: If you read carefully you will notice that the manual talks about targets and rules distinctly and talks about the default target, defining targets and defining pattern rules. I believe that's the closest the manual gets to laying this out specifically.