# Is default goal is first rule in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have simple makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = hellomake.h

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
    gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I.
```

According to makefile description "first rule in makefile is default goal". According to my understanding the first rule is:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

But I suppose this is not "default goal" since goal is to create `hellomake` executable? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile first rule target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766827/makefile-first-rule-target)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the gnu make manual, `By default, make starts with the first target (not targets whose names start with ‘.’)`.

`%.o : ...` does not count as an actual target, but rather is a pattern, which is resolved to actual goals when needed.